# Bootstrap showing only background image on android browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, android-browser

I developed a mobile site using Twitter bootstrap, site is rendering very good on desktop browsers as well as on some mobile browsers, but on android's default browser the site is only showing background image.

Can anyone tell why this problem is there?

Live site: http://logicvibes.com/demo/business-design

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Your live site is not available.

Comment: @Darpan your link's broken.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, sorry typing mistake --- http://logicvibes.com/demo/business-design

Comment: @KittMedia added the correct url.

Comment: What version of Android? Also, you're using Bootstrap v3.0.2, which is outdated.

Comment: @cvrebert Android 4.3